# Passbook."The card has expired"

Tags: ios, passbook

I'm create a pass using a [passkit](https://github.com/SimonWaldherr/passkit.php).

Pass does not open on the iPhone. When you open a pass on the Mac, under barcode is written "Card expired".Type of pass- store card.

Developer Certificate received in mid-October. What could be the problem?

I sorry for my broken English(

Comment: Hook your phone up to Xcode and view the console log while you install the pass.  If it is not a certificate problem then you are most likely missing an icon image or have invalid data in your pass.json.  If you don't have Xcode, can you post a link to the pass so we can look for you.

Comment: @PassKit,pass - https://yadi.sk/d/My89n6sqkDruy . Adding images - the logo and strip. is it possible that the problem is that there are no other images? but please see the pass (on Mac)

Comment: @PassKit, I added a picture logo, but the situation has not changed. If sending by email, open and add a card is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments - your pass isn't loading because your bundle does not contain an icon image.

```
Nov  5 17:13:34 pfr MobileSafari[9102] <Warning>: Invalid data error reading pass pass.skbonus.ru/serial-14416212108063606143. Pass does not contain icon.png/icon@2x.png/icon@3x.png
Nov  5 17:13:34 pfr MobileSafari[9102] <Error>: Invalid data error reading pass pass.skbonus.ru/serial-14416212108063606143. Pass does not contain icon.png/icon@2x.png/icon@3x.png
Nov  5 17:13:34 pfr MobileSafari[9102] <Warning>: PassBook Pass download failed: The pass cannot be read because it isn’t valid.
```